# Azure Data Factory: Wrong and unexpected Datatype conversion error during import from csv to sql server via pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am trying to load data from a csv to a SQL server database using an Azure pipeline copy data operator.It throws following error during trigger the pipeline.
In CSV file i have one date column (StatusDate) with null values when i am importing data in MS-SQL Data base table is having StatusDate is a date time column.

Error msg[![Source CSV File[image: ][1][1]]: "Operation on target Copy data1 failed: Failure happened on 'Source' side. 'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed. Please search error to get more details.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=Microsoft.Azure.Data.Governance.Plugins.Core.TypeConversionException,Message=exception occurred when converting data from column name 'StatusDate', type 'String', value 'null' to type 'DateTime': The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.FormatException,Message=The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.,Source=mscorlib,'"

Destination Table Structure:

```
create table RepsNoLongerInDiscovery(
[CRD]   [varchar](11)   ,
[First] [varchar](50)   ,
[Middle]    [varchar](50)   ,
[Last]  [varchar](50)   ,
[Suffix]    [varchar](50)   ,
[Status]    [varchar](20)   ,
[StatusDate]    [datetime]  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested with copy active and it works well.

My dataset:

[image]

Bellow is my Source:

[image]

**Note: we must specify the column data type as `DateTime` in Mapping settings**:
[image]

Then run the pipeline and check the data in Sink table:
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: In my csv file statusdate is having NULL as string. But in your it is a kind of blank value. Please correct me if i am assuming wrong.

Comment: @swad that's not blank value, it's a null value. I updated my answer. If we don't specify the source data type, I got the same error with you, please test it.

Comment: @swad what's the data look like in csv file? Is it same with me?

Comment: @swad if you have any concerns, please let me know, thank you.

Comment: Hello @swad, haven't heard you for a long time, Did you solved it now? If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: My dates are not in single quote. It's without single quote. When i am uploading it i am getting the same error. Is there any ways to correct the date format?

Comment: @swad it doesn't mater with quote. Some other way is that using data flow derivedcolumn to convert the data type, such as `toDate()` functions in expression.

Comment: @swad if you have any other concerns, please let me know!